# AngularJS, my function won't redirect to new page

Tags: angularjs, path, location

My angularJs function won't redirect to new page because $location is undefined.

Here is my controller.js:

```
wikiControllers.controller('articleController', ['$scope', 'articleService', '$routeParams', '$sanitize', 
function($scope, articleService, $routeParams, $sanitize, $location){

$scope.deleteArticle = function(){
  //articleService.deleteArticle(this.article);
  $location.path("/hjem");
}
  }]);
```

My button in .html:

```
<button ng-click="deleteArticle()" ng-confirm-click="Er du sikker på at du vil slette dette?">Slett artikkel</button>
```

Also the ng-confim-click won't show some kind of confirm box.

Comment: Is the button element inside the scope?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. but the html <button> is inside the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you haven't added $location to your array. Try this:

```
wikiControllers.controller('articleController', ['$scope', 'articleService', '$routeParams', '$sanitize', '$location', 
function($scope, articleService, $routeParams, $sanitize, $location){

$scope.deleteArticle = function(){
  //articleService.deleteArticle(this.article);
  $location.path("/hjem");
}
  }]);
```